# How to fetch multiple properties of an image using ImagePicker from expo-image-picker?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to retrieve images from the camera roll in both base64 format as well as get other information like the uri and the name of the file. Currently, the ImagePicker from expo-image-picker seems to fetch only in one of the two formats at a time.

```js
    const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
            base64: true,
        })

        if (!result.cancelled) {
            setImageSource(result.base64)
        }
    }
```

For example, if I were to specify the `base64` property as `true`, it will only fetch the image in the `base64` format, whereas if I were to do without `base64`, it will only fetch the uri. How do I fetch multiple properties of the image at the same time?

SDK Version: 34.0.0
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): iOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImagePicker will always retrieve the uri. Adding options like base64 will add to the information returned like so

```
{
  "cancelled":false,
  "height":1611,
  "width":2148,
  "uri":"file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/cropped1814158652.jpg",
  "base64":"iVBORw0KGgoAAA....."
}
```

So if you set the base64 property to true, you can retrieve the base64 format with `result.base64`

and the uri with `result.uri`